# Error: Cannot find module, for a third party library in controller.js

Tags: node.js

I am having controller.js , where I am writing a post request that uses a third party library.
But when I am importing file like

const EmailValidator = require('/email-deep-validator');

I get the error, "Error: Cannot find module".

Answer (score 0):

You need it to be

```js
const EmailValidator = require("./email-deep-validator")
```

You should omit the dot there only for node modules like

```js
fs = require('fs')
```

Comment: Is the directory correct? maybe add the whole directory there, from C:\ and so on and so forth. Also keep the .js part, it should not affect anything but a good practice, I do it, might cause some difference just this once.

Comment: const EmailValidator = require("./../node_modules/email-deep-validator")
this worked

Comment: Oh, well so the module was one directory up comparitively, to the main js file. /../ instructs the code to look up one directory, so say your code is in /project/src/, /../ will instruct it to find the file in /project/